# SpringBoot Not able to load DataSource

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to use datasource with spring boot.
In dev the application will run as spring bootrun. But in Test / Prod it will be external tomcat.
So in dev property file I am using Datasource details:

```
spring.community_ds.url=xxx
spring.community_ds.username=xxx
spring.community_ds.password=xxx
spring.community_ds.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
spring.community_ds.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

And in TEST/PROD want to use JNDI

```
spring.community_ds.jndi-name=xxxx
```

Now in code I am trying to get the DataSource to create JdbcTemplate

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.community_ds")
@Bean(name = "communityDb")
public DataSource communityDbDataSource() {

    DataSource ds = DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    //Getting error db url is Null here
    return ds;
}

@Bean(name = "communityDbTemplate")
public JdbcTemplate communityDbTemplate(@Qualifier("communityDb") DataSource communityDb) {
    return new JdbcTemplate(communityDb);
}
```

I also tried :

```
@Configuration
public class DatabaseConfig {

@Autowired
Environment env;

@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
@Bean
@Primary
public DataSource getDataSource() {
    DataSource dsp =  DataSourceBuilder
            .create().build();


    System.out.println(env.getProperty("spring.community_ds.url"));
    System.out.println(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.url"));

    return dsp;
}
}
```

Here also I saw env.getProperty is printing the data properly, but when I debugged inside DataSourceBuilder the url/username etc are null.

In gradle first I used:

```
compile("org.springframework:spring-jdbc")
```

Which was giving some error hence used:

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc")
```

Comment: that means `DataSourceAutoConfiguration` is not kicking in. Have you excluded any AutoConfiguration in your project? Or Do you find this class in your project. try to Search.

Comment: Do you have multiple datasources in your application? If not why the added complexity of your own configuration.

Comment: I deleted my answer, cause it was just wrong, sorry...